# Using Tenary Operator

Tags: javascript

I am practicing using Tenary operator but as a result it shows undefined. I don't know where I am doing mistake in this code. could you please help me.

```js
let userName = prompt(`Enter Your User Name`);
let pass = prompt(`Enter Your Password`);

let message;

(userName === `Employee` && pass === 1234) ? message = `Hello ${userName}`:
  (userName === `Director` && pass === 4567) ? message = `Hello ${userName}` :
  (userName === `` || pass === ``) ? message = `One or More field is blank` : `Denied`;

console.log(message);
```

Comment: Don't use a ternary operator for that, it's all-but-impossible to follow anyway.

Comment: Never use a side effect to set a value like that

Comment: I'd suggest you to use ternary operator for basic, simple conditions. Even if you find and fix your condition it is  not readable. It would be better to  use simple if/else in your case.

Comment: Enclose expected passwords into quotes (i.e. `'1234'`) as `pass` type is string, so `===` would return `false`

Comment: It is as ugly as a `switch (true)`

Answer (score 1):

You need a single assignment outside of the expression.

Then you need to check against strings, because `prompt` returns either `null` for cancelling or a string.

Another hint, if a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) does not contain a dynamic content, please use strings instead, this is faster and soes not irritate.

**Warning: Please do not use this kind of nested structure. It is prone for errors and could be replaced with a function and early exit.**

```js
let userName = prompt('Enter Your User Name');
let pass = prompt('Enter Your Password');

let message = userName === 'Employee' && pass === '1234'
    ? `Hello ${userName}`
    : userName === 'Director' && pass === '4567'
        ? `Hello ${userName}`
        : userName === '' || pass === ''
            ? 'One or More field is blank'
            : 'Denied';

console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the conditional operator is that it forms an expression which evaluates to a result value, so that it can be used e.g. in

```
const message = …
```

You've used assignment expressions as operands to it though, which makes it just a poor copy of an `if`/`else` statement:

```
if (userName === `Employee` && pass === 1234) message = `Hello ${userName}`
else if (userName === `Director` && pass === 4567) message = `Hello ${userName}`
else if (userName === `` || pass === ``) message = `One or More field is blank`
else `Denied` ;
```

And in the last block, you forgot the assignment so the `message` variable kept its `undefined` value.

Instead, it should be

```
const message = (userName === `Employee` && pass === 1234)
   ? `Hello ${userName}`
   : (userName === `Director` && pass === 4567)
     ? `Hello ${userName}`
     : (userName === `` || pass === ``)
       ? `One or More field is blank`
       : `Denied`;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are comparing using the `===` operator (which checks for value and type) the pass variable to a Number type, but what prompt actually does is set a String type to pass.
if you want it to work, just change the code to the following:

````
let userName = prompt(`Enter Your User Name`);
let pass = prompt(`Enter Your Password`);

let message;

(userName === `Employee` && pass === "1234") ? message = `Hello ${userName}`:
  (userName === `Director` && pass === "4567") ? message = `Hello ${userName}` :
  (userName === `` || pass === ``) ? message = `One or More field is blank` : `Denied`;

console.log(message);```
````

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use`if` statement instead of ternary if you only have these 3 - 4 conditions
and would not be going beyond that

Note: Avoid using nested ternary operator.

```js
const userName = prompt(`Enter Your User Name`);
const pass = prompt(`Enter Your Password`);
let message = 'Denied';

if (userName === `Employee` && pass === 1234) {
  message = `Hello ${userName}`;
} else if (userName === `Director` && pass === 4567) {
  message = `Hello ${userName}`;
} else if (userName === '' || pass === '') {
  message = `One or More field is blank`;
}

console.log(message);
```

**Option 2**

if you may have more options like this then try this approach
Note: This is just a pseudo code and you might have to change it to make it work :)

```js
const validLoginDetails = [
  {
    name: 'Employee',
    password: 1234,
  },
  {
    name: 'Director',
    password: 4567,
  },
];

const hasValidLogin = validLoginDetails.find(
  ({ name, password }) => name === userName && password === pass,
);

if (hasValidLogin) {
  message = `Hello ${userName}`;
} else if (userName === '' || pass === '') {
  message = `One or More field is blank`;
}
```